# JavaFX doesn't change the font of its components

Tags: java, user-interface, fonts, javafx, textfield

I specified a font in a style .css file:

```
-fx-background-color: #1e1c1e;
-fx-font-family: "Segoe UI", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
```

but IDEA underlines the second line:
"mismatched property value null".
Then I tried to set a font in the following way:

```
inputField.setFont(Font.font("Segoe UI"));
```

All the same. Font won't change. I'd like to ask your help because I'm stucked with this issue.

Comment: It is possible that the font doesn't exist in the system

Comment: Can you post a full [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?